# If the Timer starts itself will the code that ran in past will ever be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I have a .net based windows service with the following pseudo code. It just goes in loop and based on a condition it either does DoTask() instantly or after 60 seconds. It is done this way to prevent overlapping timer calls when DoTask() is already running.

My question is - if done this way, the code/objects that have already run in DoTask() will ever be garbage collected? Or, since the timer is started from within the DoTask() which is called by timer, the memory stack will just keep increasing?

```
//called once when the service starts
function_startup
{
    mainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    mainTimer.Interval = 10;
    mainTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    mainTimer.AutoReset = false;  // makes it fire only once
    mainTimer.Start();
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //some business logic goes here
    DoTask();
}

private void DoTask()
{
   //some business logic goes here
   //will the code that is here be garbage collected eventually 
   //or will always stay in memory stack increasing the memory that the service takes while running?

   //if condition a, run DoTask immediately again.
   if (condition_a)
   {
       mainTimer.Interval = 10;
       mainTimer.Start();
   }
   //else if condition b, sleep for a minute and then DoTask
   else (condition_b)
   {
       mainTimer.Interval = 60000; //run after 60 seconds
       mainTimer.Start();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no memory leak in your code, and also nothing more gets collected or created (from what you have shown).

1. With the code shown, the *timer* itself will never be collected or recreated.
2. If you instantiate classes or structs in the scope of `DoTask()`, they will fall out of scope when it finishes then will be collected eventually.

Comment: Thanks. The service I have starts off at 50,000k of memory when processing small things. After a new heavy duty stuff is processed (instantiating bigger classes, processing, etc), it goes up to 300,000k. When the processing is done, it does not seem to go back down - I waited hours. Any good ways to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: @JohnWatt use a memory profiler, however be aware, .Net will not aggressively reclaim memory and give it back to the operating unless it feels it needs to. This would be inefficient